# Problems in saving sessions with some vim plugins

Tags: vim, vim-plugin

Trying to put together a Vim setup using [NERDTree](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1658), [session](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=3150) and [tabbar](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1338).

Unfortunately tabbar (which is based on [minibufexpl](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=159)) does not go well with the session plugin.

Is there a workaround/alternative for this? Or do I have to give up one of these plugins.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe, tabbar/minibufexpl does not have session support at all, no matter whether you use “session” plugin or `:mksession` directly. To make tabbar work with sessions you must, at first, setup a `BufReadCmd` that will invoke tabbar on *already opened* buffer that has a name `-TabBar-`. Maybe it is better to also rename `-TabBar-` to `//TabBar//` because with autocmd invoked for `-TabBar-` you lose the ability to open/create file with name `-TabBar-` completely, but with `//TabBar//` nothing is lost. Note though, that BufReadCmd may be not enough.